# Can I get to know which button I pressed in this jframe form and perform a action on it?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am doing a simple project on gas booking in Netbeans using xampp for the database. In one of my JFrame form, there is a "view bookings" button, which shows the details of the bookings. And it has 4 columns and one of the column names is "type_of_gas".

Is there a way to know which button I pressed in the image shown or perform an action on it? So I can display the gas type in the "type_of_gas" column.
Suppose:

```
if(button 1 is pressed)
{
display("Indane gas ");
}
if(button 2 is pressed)
{
display("Bharat gas ");
}
if(button 3 is pressed)
{
display("Hp gas ");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is **implement ActionListener** for your form class and then add the abstract method **actionPerformed()** to the class then set the **name** property for each button on your form then yes, for example:

```
public class MyForm extends javax.swing.JFrame implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

    public MyForm() {
        initializeForm();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private initializeForm() {
        // Create your Form here...
        javax.swing.JButton indaneButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Indane Gas Booking");
        indaneButton.setName("indanebutton");
        // Layout and other possible stuff for this button here...

        javax.swing.JButton bharatButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Bharat Gas Booking");
        indaneButton.setName("bharatbutton");
        // Layout and other possible stuff for this button here...

        javax.swing.JButton hpButton = new javax.swing.JButton("HP Gas Booking");
        indaneButton.setName("hpbutton");
        // Layout and other possible stuff for this button here...

       // Other form components ..........
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton) evt.getSource();
        switch (button.getName().toLowerCase()) {
            // Button 1
            case "indanebutton":  // As supplied in 1st button's name property.
                // Do Stuff...
                break;

            // Button 2
            case "bharatbutton":  // As supplied in 2nd button's name property.
                // Do More Stuff...
                break;

            // Button 3
            case "hpbutton":  // As supplied in 3rd button's name property.
                // Do Even More Stuff...
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
```

This is **just and example** not a runnable.

Comment: @von - If this answer was helpful for you then please don't forget to Accept it by selecting the Up Arrow on the top-left corner of the answer post.